# java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long in Kotlin (when the initial value is null)

Tags: kotlin

If I have the following, it works (i.e. number get assign 1000)

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var number: Long ? = null // or number = 0
    val simpleObject = SimpleClass()
    number = 1000
    println("Hi + $number")
}
```

If I have the following, it works (i.e. number get assign 1000)

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var number: Long = 0
    val simpleObject = SimpleClass()
    number = simpleObject.getValue<Long>()
    println("Hi + $number")
}

class SimpleClass() {
    fun <T>getValue(): T {
        return 1000 as T
    }
}
```

But if I have the below, it fails

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var number: Long? = null
    val simpleObject = SimpleClass()
    number = simpleObject.getValue<Long>()
    println("Hi + $number")
}

class SimpleClass() {
    fun <T>getValue(): T {
        return 1000 as T
    }
}
```

The error reported is on the `number = simpleObject.getValue<Long>()` line

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Why when I initialise `var number: Long ? = null` and `var number: Long = 0` have different result? Did I get anything wrong?

**UPDATED**

A workaround using the below, the result is okay. But an additional temp variable is used.

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var number: Long? = null
    val simpleObject = SimpleClass()
    val temp = simpleObject.getValue<Long>()
    number = temp
    println("Hi + $number")
}

class SimpleClass() {
    fun <T>getValue(): T {
        return 1000 as T
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take a look into generated bytecode:

```
fun <T> getValue(): T {
    return 1000 as T
}

// becomes

public final getValue()Ljava/lang/Object;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 17 L0
    SIPUSH 1000
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Integer.valueOf (I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    CHECKCAST java/lang/Object
    ARETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this LSimpleClass; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

As you can see, this method **does not cast** `1000` to a `Long` it simply ensures, that the object is of type `java/lang/Object` (well, it is) and returns the `1000` as an `Integer` object.

Therefore, you may call (note: call only) this method with any type and this will not throw exception. However, storing the result in a variable invokes real cast which may lead to `ClassCastException`

```
fun f3() {
    val simpleObject = SimpleClass()
    // L0
    //   LINENUMBER 16 L0
    //   NEW SimpleClass
    //   DUP
    //   INVOKESPECIAL SimpleClass.<init> ()V
    //   ASTORE 0

    simpleObject.getValue<SimpleClass>() // no problems
    // L1
    //   LINENUMBER 17 L1
    //   ALOAD 0
    //   INVOKEVIRTUAL SimpleClass.getValue ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    //   POP

    val number = simpleObject.getValue<SimpleClass>() // throws ClassCastException1
    // L2
    //   LINENUMBER 18 L2
    //   ALOAD 0
    //   INVOKEVIRTUAL SimpleClass.getValue ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    //   CHECKCAST SimpleClass
    //   ASTORE 1


    // L3
    //   LINENUMBER 19 L3
    //   RETURN
    // L4
    //   LOCALVARIABLE number LSimpleClass; L3 L4 1
    //   LOCALVARIABLE simpleObject LSimpleClass; L1 L4 0
    //   MAXSTACK = 2
    //   MAXLOCALS = 2
}
```

But why storing the result as a `Long?` throws an exception? Again, let's take a look at the differences in bytecode:

```
var number: Long? = null              |    var number: Long = 0
                                      |
      ACONST_NULL                     |        LCONST_0
      CHECKCAST java/lang/Long        |        LSTORE 0                
      ASTORE 0                        |

                number = simpleObject.getValue<Long>() [both]

      ALOAD 1                         |
              INVOKEVIRTUAL SimpleClass.getValue ()Ljava/lang/Object; [both]
      CHECKCAST java/lang/Long        |        CHECKCAST java/lang/Number
      ASTORE 0                        |        INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Number.longValue ()J
                                      |        LSTORE 0
```

As you can see, the bytecode for `number: Long` casts the function result to a `Number` and then calls `Number.longValue` in order to convert the value to a `Long` (`long` in Java)

However, the bytecode for `number: Long?` casts the function result directly into the `Long?` (`Long` in Java) which leads to `ClassCastException`.

Not sure, if this behavior documented somewhere. However, the `as` operator performs unsafe cast and the compiler warns about it:

```
Warning:(21, 16) Kotlin: Unchecked cast: kotlin.Int to T
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the excellent detail technical reason behind the 2 dex codes generated. This explains well. I think the Kotlin language should improve where it could cast to java/lang/Number instead of java/lang/Long directly. So in short for now, they are just different. Upvote your answer and tick to accept it. Thanks!!

Comment: do you think this is the intended behaviour ?

Comment: @voddan not sure. This behavior might not be obvious at the first glance, but what should Kotlin do when the developer says "hey, I know, that this cast is unsafe, but trust me"? It warns about possible class cast exception, and it is right. It should probably explain some low-level reasons behind the warning, or at least provide a link to the docs (long live Rust with awesome compile error explanations)

Comment: a cast from Int to Double should never succeed

Comment: @voddan sure, I'm just talking about warning message improvements

Comment: I recommend you fill the issue in YT

Answer (score 1):

```
return 1000 as T
```

is an unchecked cast, and the compiler issues a warning about it. You're returning an Integer, always, but you pretend it's a T. That will only work fine if T is actually Integer. In all other cases, it will fail.

The obviousness of the problem would be more blatant if you chose a completely unrelated type like, I don't know, StringBuilder:

```
var number: StringBuilder? = null
val simpleObject = SimpleClass()
number = simpleObject.getValue<StringBuilder>()
```

Now you should realize that this doesn't make sense: you're calling a method that is supposed to return a StringBuilder, but it returns 1000.